# AWS S3 Bucket - Logs for open bucket which is accessed by browser or any scan program

Tags: log-files, amazon-s3

If any s3 bucket is opened whose directory listing can be seen in a browser or any python based scan program, where should I check logs for such bucket?

If any s3 bucket is not public but its objects are public. It means directory listing of bucket is disabled but if any one as object url, object can be downloaded. Where should one see the access log of such bucket?

We can see all the logs who has opened the url either by browser or by any program in access.log file of apache, similar file I am searching for s3 bucket, I want to know if any IP has accessed the bucket or object url.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable S3 logs.

> To track requests for access to your bucket, you can enable server
>   access logging. Each access log record provides details about a single
>   access request, such as the requester, bucket name, request time,
>   request action, response status, and an error code, if relevant.

[How to Enable Server Access Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html#server-access-logging-overview)

[Configuring Web Traffic Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LoggingWebsiteTraffic.html)

Comment: s3 logs are showing GET, PUT and similar requests which are created through access and secret keys. It does not show the entry if any one tries to open my bucket in browser. Either bucket will show content listing or access denied error, both are not there in logs.